# How do I put text on multiple lines in a forest tree within a gb4e example?

Tags: line-breaking, tikz-trees, forest, linguistics, gb4e

I'm using gb4e and forest to present (linguistic) trees in a nice format. It's been working well except that I some of the text underneath the nodes presented on multiple lines. In the forest package readme I've found the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[extra]{tipa}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
% For delinked segments
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.text}
\tikzset{delink/.style={
    decorate,
    postaction={decorate,
    decoration={text along path,
        text align=center,
        text={|\tiny|=},
        transform={rotate=90}}}}}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{xlist}
\ex
\begin{forest} GP1 [
 [parent
 [child]
 [child]
 [a very\\tall\\child, align=center, base=bottom]
 ]
 ]
\end{forest}
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Which yields what I want, namely that the text is displayed on multiple lines.

[image]

However when I apply this method to my own tree, I encounter the problem that it does not put the text on multiple lines. Here is the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[extra]{tipa}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
% For delinked segments
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.text}
\tikzset{delink/.style={
    decorate,
    postaction={decorate,
    decoration={text along path,
        text align=center,
        text={|\tiny|=},
        transform={rotate=90}}}}}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex
 \begin{xlist}
 \ex
 \begin{forest} GP1 [
 [x[k]]
 [x[\textipa{1}
 [a very\\tall\\child, align=center, base=bottom]
 ]]
 [x[z]]
 [x[\textipa{1}[| |]]]
 [x[n]]
 ]\end{forest}
 \end{xlist}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Which yields the following output.

[image]

Is there any way to fix this is issue and make the text appear on multiple lines?

EDIT: edited to include MWE

Comment: Can you provide an MWE that compiles, and not just code fragments?  Welcome to the site.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Edited to include MWE's

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I've edited my answer in your honour. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `gb4e`, but with the definition of the `GP1` style in `forest`. There are at least three ways to fix this:

### Use an explicit `tabular`

You can put the node inside an explicit `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[extra]{tipa}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{gb4e}

% For delinked segments
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.text}
\tikzset{delink/.style={
decorate,
postaction={decorate,
decoration={text along path,
    text align=center,
    text={|\tiny|=},
    transform={rotate=90}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex
 \begin{xlist}
 \ex
 \begin{forest} GP1 [
 [x[k]]
 [x[\textipa{1}
 [{\begin{tabular}{c}a very\\tall\\child\end{tabular}}]
 ]]
 [x[z]]
 [x[\textipa{1}[| |]]]
 [x[n]]
 ]\end{forest}
 \end{xlist}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### Use the `stackengine` package

Alternatively, you could use the `stackengine` package to do the same thing:

```
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{forest} GP1 [
  [x[k]]
  [x[\textipa{1}
  [{\Shortunderstack[c]{{a very} tall child}}]
  ]]
  [x[z]]
  [x[\textipa{1}[| |]]]
  [x[n]]
]\end{forest}
```

### Redefine the `forest` `GP1` style

If you're going to be doing this a lot, it might make more sense to redefine the `GP1` style slightly, so that the nodes behave as you would expect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[extra]{tipa}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{gb4e}
% For delinked segments
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.text}
\tikzset{delink/.style={
decorate,
postaction={decorate,
decoration={text along path,
    text align=center,
    text={|\tiny|=},
    transform={rotate=90}}}}}
\forestset{GP1/.style 2 args={
    for n={1}{baseline},
    s sep=0pt, l sep=0pt,
    for descendants={
      l sep=0pt, l={#1},
      anchor=base,calign=first,child anchor=north,
      inner xsep=1pt,inner ysep=2pt,outer sep=0pt,s sep=0pt
    },
    delay={
      if content={}{phantom}{for children={no edge}},
      for tree={
        if content={O}{tier=OR}{},
        if content={R}{tier=OR}{},
        if content={N}{tier=N}{},
        if content={x}{
          tier=x,content={$\times$},outer xsep={#2},
          for tree={calign=center},
          for descendants={content format={\noexpand\standardnodestrut\forestoption{content}}},
          before drawing tree={outer xsep=0pt,delay={typeset node}},
          s sep=4pt
        }{align=center}, % changed the style here
      },
    },
    before drawing tree={where content={}{parent anchor=center,child anchor=center}{}},
  }}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex
 \begin{xlist}
 \ex
 \begin{forest} GP1 [
 [x[k]]
 [x[\textipa{1}
 [{a very\\ tall \\child}]
 ]]
 [x[z]]
 [x[\textipa{1}[| |]]]
 [x[n]]
 ]\end{forest}
 \end{xlist}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```